# Ipython jupyter_client get python object

Tags: ipython, zeromq

I am working on a custom implementation of IPython and I would like to know if it is possible to get python raw objects from the kernel (and not just the str outputs sent from the kernel). I was not able to find any magic command to pass to the kernel to get raw object

Thank you for any comment on this question